# Detect first ul element and change li inside or create new li with jquery .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, find

I need to know how to detect the first, second or third ul element in a specific div or form. What I am trying do is once a `ul` is detected on the page, I want to change the `li`s in the second ul element.

```
var ulcountfood = $('#nl-form').find('ul').length;
        alert(ulcountfood);
        //Change second ul li List html
```

Comment: show us what you have tried till now?

Comment: I only counted the elements and really got no idea how to trigger the first second or third ul after that   i change the li inside with .html().

Comment: check below my suggestion , i hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use `.eq()` to determine if the current `ul` is first, second and so on.

Please refer to documentation : https://api.jquery.com/eq/

So for each `ul` you need to check for its index,

```
$('#nl-form').find('ul').each(function(){

   if($(this).eq(0)) {
     //do your first ul specific logic
   } // and so on for other ul

});
```